# WPF Window.owner doesnt work with window.show()

Tags: c#, wpf

So when I use

```
 Feed newfeed = new Feed(x);
 newfeed.Owner = this;
 newfeed.Show();
 this.Close();
```

It closes First window , Debug automatically stopped , No errors . No exceptions .
but when I use

> newfeed.ShowDialog();

It open the second window , doesnt close the first window .

What I want is to close open second window in top of first window , then close First window.

Comment: `newFeed.ShowDialog()` blocks, i.e. doesn't return, until `newFeed` is closed. Why do you use `ShowDialog()` if you want to close the first window anyway...?

Comment: yeah thats why i use show() . but it not working when used newfeed.owner = this;

Comment: Why do you set the `Owner` to a window that you close just aftewards?

Comment: I want to start second window  top of the firstwindow . Now I tried using newfeed.WindowStartupLocation = this.WindowStartupLocation; and doesnt seems to work either ;

Comment: while using  windowstartuplocation="Manual" in second window

Comment: Is the first window the main application window? Not sure but I think that when you close the main window is like closing the whole application. In that case, you may want to launch a new process with your second window with `Process.Start`. Alternatively you can try to reduce the size of the first window so it is smaller than the second window so it remains hidden (don't forget to  move the first  window position accordingly when the second window is moved)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ShowDialog()` blocks and won't return until the dialog window has been closed.

If you want to simply position the `newFeed` window based on the current window's position, you could set the `WindowStartupLocation` to `WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner` and then set the `Owner` property back to `null` and close the current window as soon as the new window has been loaded:

```
Feed newfeed = new Feed(x);
newfeed.Owner = this;
newfeed.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
RoutedEventHandler eventHandler = null;
eventHandler += (ss, ee) =>
{
    newfeed.Loaded -= eventHandler;
    newfeed.Owner = null;
    this.Close();
};
newfeed.Loaded += eventHandler;
newfeed.Show();
```

You could also set the `WindowStartupLocation` to `Manual` and calculate and set the `Left` and `Top` properties of the new window yourself. But using `WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner` and an event handler as shown in the sample above is probably simpler and still gets the job done.